# Bootstrap 3 Grid Carousel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, carousel

I'm trying to make a carousel with multiple grid elements. I want to do this with Bootstrap 3 but I can't get it.

**This is how I want the carousel.**
[Carousel showing a grid system rather than a single image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqZw8.jpg)

Some expert who can help me?

Comment: try using a div with a class row inside item, you should be able to use the grid normally

Comment: I have done this in the past by making the Carousel content a row or in this case a table with multiple cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use each carousel item as a container for your cell based content.  In this case I used a table to hold some images, but one might just as well have used a bootstrap row.

```css
td {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/72/72/);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 2px aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr><td></td><td rowspan="2"></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr><td rowspan="2"></td><td></td><td rowspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
td {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/72/72/);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 2px aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr><td></td><td rowspan="2"></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr><td rowspan="2"></td><td></td><td rowspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```